# Access violation with getline in thread + boost::function

Tags: c++, boost, getline

I was going to write a class which reads `std::cin` in a thread and calls a callback when something was entered. The callback is a `boost::function`. The code runs if I only have the `std::getline (std::cin, command);` , but crashes with "access violation" if I add the line `if(this->m_receiveHandler != NULL)`. I really cannot find what's happening, so I reduced the problem down to the following test.

The problem is not fully deterministic, sometimes I can enter a line or two, sometimes it crashes immediately. The last thing the program outputs is always "access receiver handler".

```
class InputReader
{
private:
    boost::function<void (const char*, unsigned int) > m_receiveHandler;
    boost::thread m_receiveThread;

    void receiveLoop(void)
    {

        while(true)
        {
            std::string command;
            std::getline (std::cin, command);
            std::cout << "access receiver handler" << std::flush;               
            if(this->m_receiveHandler != NULL)
            {
            }           
        }

    }

public:
    InputReader()
    {
        m_receiveThread = boost::thread(boost::bind(&InputReader::receiveLoop, this));
    }


};

TEST(InputReaderTest, WaitInfinite)
{
    InputReader reader;
    while (true) {};
}
```

Do you see anything wrong with this code?

EDIT: I am compiling with GCC 4.3.2 on Suse Linux with Boost 1.49.

Comment: `m_receiveHandler` is not a pointer, can you safely compare it to `NULL`? It is possible that line is trying to create a `boost::function` from `NULL`. EDIT: There is an [`empty()`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/boost/function.html#idp16224640-bb) member function you might use.

Comment: I just tried this with VS2010, except for `TEST()` where I just placed `InputReader read;` in `main()` instead and received no seg fault after several entries in `stdin`. Is this the entire code that seg faults and you have definitely rebuilt?

Comment: @BoBTFish: It's a bit weird, but there is an undocumented constructor to convert a null pointer constant to an empty function; so `f != NULL` gives the same boolean value as `f` (or `!f.empty()` if you like verbosity).

Comment: I guess, the code crashes in the real code, but doesn't crash in the above test, does it? It's the object lifetime issue: the 'InputReader` instance got already destroyed when you attempt to access its member within the thread. Note that all the previous lines (`getline`) do not access any object memebers, so they never crash.

Comment: @IgorR.: it's this test which crashes. I haven't used the class in real code, yet.

Comment: @hmjd: thanks for trying. I have just added the information about my platform. The question is: Does that mean it's a problem with GCC or does that mean that Windows/VS2010 simply doesn't detect the problem (if it's there)?

Comment: @BoBTFish: I had checked the documentation which says comparing to NULL is ok before. Now I also tried `if(!m_receiveHandler.empty())` which gives the same effect.

Comment: @Philipp ok, I see. Then maybe you've got some ODR violation? Check that you link and `# include` the same version of boost (perhaps you've got 2 version installed on your machine and mix them by accident).

Answer (score 1):

I've just tried this with clang on OSX and it works (replaced boost with std though). What happens when you start the thread in a different public member function? 
The boost function variable is in effect a shared variable between two threads and should probably be protected by some concurrency primitive. The thread might actually see an incomplete snapshot of the 'this' object. It doesn't explain why it works two times before failing though.
If you know what the receiveHandler will be at construction time and you don't need to change it you have the option of passing the boost::function as a parameter to the thread (a copy or even a move might do).